# Angular 8: "Please add a @NgModule annotation" when including a library into another library

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I want to use one of my shared libraries in another shared library, but I am getting

```
ERROR: Unexpected value 'LibraryModule in ...' imported by the module 'TestlibModule in ...'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

The libraries are in separate angular apps (test and test2). 
Each app contains one library (generated through ng generate library) which I build by running ng build library_name

a library in the test app (called testlib) includes the library from test2 (called library) through npm

package.json:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
  ...
  "library": "file:../../test2/test2/dist/library"
},
```

testlib.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TestlibComponent } from './testlib.component';
import { LibraryModule } from 'library';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [TestlibComponent],
  imports: [
    LibraryModule
  ],
  exports: [TestlibComponent]
})
export class TestlibModule { }
```

tsconfig.lib.json in the included library

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

LibraryModule can be included without any problems into an application, but it crashes with the mentioned error when included into a library. I cannot find out what I am doing wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you share the Module in which you are importing TestlibModule and also the RoutingModule, where you are implementing lazy loading.

Comment: @AnoopRajasekharaWarrier: Thanks for the reply. In order to simplify the example as much as possible, no routing or lazy loading is involved. The TestlibModule is also not used anywhere (it crashes on build - ng build testlib). These are complately new and empty angular apps generated by ng new.

Comment: Can you push the code to git or stackblitz and share the details. With this info, I am not in a position to comment any thing.

Comment: Here is the example: https://github.com/cleb/angularmoduleerrorexample.git.
Steps to reproduce: cd test2/test2;npm install;ng build library;cd ../../test/test;npm install;ng build testlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have 2 project test and test2. In test and test2 project, you have a library each.

Step to fix the issue:

1. Test2 Project:

   a. npm i

   b. npm build library

   c. Go to the dist folder where you have the library build, then run "npm pack". This will generate a .tgz file. Copy that and paste that in test project. For that, create a folder (called packages), then paste here.
2. Test Project:

   a. In package.json, replace the file path for library as:
    "library": "file:./packages/library.1.0.0.tgz",

   Here library.1.0.0.tgz is name of the tgz file generated after npm pack. You may rename that.

   b. npm i

   c. npm run build and ng build testLib.

   d. Try running the application, now using ng serve command. Hopefully this works.

**Note**: The steps you need to follow sequentially.

Comment: Thank you, this has solved the issue. Can you help me understand why my approach didn't work and why it does work with npm pack?

Comment: This is because, if the library was within the project, the you could have given the path in tsConfig. But in this scenario, you have the library in another angular project. You could have created multiple library in the same project. Best approach is to npm pack, add that to location and access from there. Thank you for the updates. Glad to know it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I found one more solution:

In your library project (*testlib*) where you import your module *TestlibModule* from your library set

*"fullTemplateTypeCheck": **false***, in  `angularCompilerOptions`

So, update `tsconfig.lib.json` file for *testlib* project with this

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
      ...
      "fullTemplateTypeCheck": false,
      ...
}
```

Now both libraries are building fine and you can import them in any app as well